# SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON in docker

Tags: docker, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app which starts fine in cmd line:

```
export SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON='...'
java org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher
```

But when I do it with docker:

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 --env SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON='...' foo/bar
```

The app starts but cannot see the properties defined in `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON`.
But the `ENV_VAR` is **set**, I can see it in the logs because of the app prints `System.getenv()` in the main method.

The app which runs fine in the cmd line is created from the image (docker export...), so both apps are identical.

What's going wrong here?

Comment: To narrow the problem, are you able to set any other environment variables and see whether the docker container reflects the change? e.g. change the port with SERVER_PORT= or the SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME  and see if that changes in the startup logs. It could be related to the json formatting of the content of that variable - perhaps some escaping of quotes within the quotes string is necessary

Comment: Another thing to check is whether it works via a compose file like in https://github.com/box/mojito/blob/master/docker/docker-compose.yml#L26